# What are the advantages of created a custom package?

Tags: theme

What are the advantages of created MyPackage/MyTheme instead of default/MyTheme ?

Since app/design/frontend/default/default is almost completely empty (no template folder, no local.xml) we could customize files here.

In skin/frontend/default/default no customizations or they will be overwrite in case of magento update. So we could do our customizations in default/MyTheme.

So the only disadvantage with default/MyTheme is that the skin/frontend/default/default fallback would be useless.

I guess there is others reasons of created MyPackage/MyTheme as recommended by Magento but i can't figure out them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until 1.9CE you got better theme fallback creating theme under `default/mytheme`:

```
default/mytheme -> default/default -> base/default
```

with `mypackage/mytheme` you get:

```
mypackage/mytheme -> mypackage/default -> base/default
```

This means if you wanted templates and layout etc to fall back to the `default/default` theme you would need to create `mypackage/default` being an exact duplicate of `default/default`.  So it's more efficient to create your theme under `default/mytheme`.  1.9CE however introduces infinite theme fallback which makes this point irrelevant as you can now define which theme you want your theme to fallback to.  This is done very simply in `app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/etc/theme.xml` where you can use something along the lines of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>default/default</parent>
</theme>
```

So before 1.9CE you get better fallback creating a theme under the `default` package, but from 1.9CE onwards there is no advantage/disadvantage either way, just create the theme wherever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. So in the end if we don't need a theme in default package then we create our custom package. It's more clear. I didn't know about the infinite theme fallback in 1.9CE, that's nice :)